# Controller edit method, modify object data before commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When a user saves a form, I want to do the following check before saving

```
if header2 is null
header2 = header1
```

I don't want to add validation and stop the save action, because header2 is only needed in rare occasions. 
I'm not sure how to have the update method in the controller do this. The command to commit the update is

`if @entry.update_attributes(params[:entry])`

So should I be modifying the params[:entry][:header2] field? I tried to do this with the following code but it isn't updating

```
params[:entry][:header2] = params[:entry][:header1]
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm starting to feel I should handle this on the client side with javascript instead.

--EDIT: Added to original Post Below--

I have tried coderama's suggestions below and neither work for me

```
  validate :data_present

  def data_present
    self.header2 = self.header1 if self.header2 == nil
  end
```

and

```
  def update
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    params[:entry][:header2] = params[:entry][:header1] unless params[:entry][:header2].present?    

    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.update_attributes(params[:entry])....
```

SQL

```
mysql> select header1, header2 from entries where title = "new";
+---------+---------+
| header1 | header2 |
+---------+---------+
| Blah    | NULL    |
+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want be able to open in edit mode, change nothing (field is already null) and hit save and have this code changed. Have also tried for making new entry records and it doesn't work there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, along with the specs to prove

**/app/models/model_name.rb**

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :header_1, :header_2
  before_validation :header_check

  def header_check
    return if self.header_2.blank?
    self.header_1 = self.header_2 if self.header_1.blank?
  end

end
```

**And the spec: /spec/models/model_name_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ModelName do

  before(:each) do
    @model_name = ModelName.new
    @header_one_text = "HeaderOneText"
    @header_two_text = "HeaderTwoText"
  end
  it "should should set header 2 if header 1 is blank" do
    @model_name.header_2 = @header_two_text
    @model_name.valid?
    @model_name.header_1.should == @header_two_text
  end

  it "should leave header 1 if both are set" do
    @model_name.header_1 = @header_one_text
    @model_name.header_2 = @header_two_text
    @model_name.valid?
    @model_name.header_1.should == @header_one_text
  end

end
```

Comment: See, here I up-voted your answer ;). But you should exchange `header_1` with `header_2`. He want `header2` to be set to `header1` if `header2` is empty. And you don't need `attr_accessor` for those fields if they are in db.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your own options, these could be possible solutions which I have both used successfully depending on my circumstances.

**Option 1 - Model Validation**

Create a custom validation or a validation based on a condition. E.g.

```
class Body < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :hair, :unless => lambda { |o| o.age > 80 }

  validate :multiple_heads

  def multiple_heads
    self.head = "No head" if self.head == nil
  end
end
```

**Option 2 - Modify the hash in the controller**

Your second suggestion will also work. E.g.

```
params[:entry][:header2] = params[:entry][:header1] unless params[:entry][:header2].present?
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried both suggestions and neither is working. This does seem a little bizarre. I'll update my original post with the current source code

Comment: I think modifications of a record during its validation are merely discarded as soon as the validator returns.